# QThreadPool causing freezes when loading QImage in Qt5, when perfectly smooth in Qt4

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside2

I made a widget for loading lots of images in a deferred fashion by using threads. When using Python 2 (with `PySide`), the scrolling is super smooth with all the threads running. On Python 3 (with `PySide2`), it freezes every time you attempt to scroll.

I narrowed it down to the `QtGui.QImage` call within the thread.

```
class ImageLoader(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
        super(ImageLoader, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        QtGui.QImage(self.item.path)  # shortened to the min reproducible example
```

Does anyone know why it would only be causing issues on newer versions of Qt, and perhaps how I can fix the issue?

Here's the full script, trimmed down as much as I was able to. Resizing the window or scrolling will be smooth in `PySide`, and in `PySide2` it will freeze until all the threads have finished.

```
PATH_TO_LARGE_FILE = 'C:/large_image.png'  # Pick something >1MB to really show the slowness

import sys
from Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class GridView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GridView, self).__init__()
        self.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.setModel(GridModel())

class GridModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GridModel, self).__init__()
        self.threadPool = QtCore.QThreadPool()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole):
        # Load image
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            item = self.itemFromIndex(index)
            worker = ImageLoader(item)
            self.threadPool.start(worker)
            return None

        # Set size of icons
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole:
            return QtCore.QSize(64, 89)
        return super(GridModel, self).data(index, role)

class ImageLoader(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
        super(ImageLoader, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        QtGui.QImage(self.item.path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = GridView()
    for i in range(1000):
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem('test {}'.format(i))
        item.path = PATH_TO_LARGE_FILE
        widget.model().appendRow(item)
    widget.show()
    app.setActiveWindow(widget)
    app.exec_()
```

**Edit (requested in comments):** [Link to full script](https://pastebin.com/gt3azbLA)

**Edit (March 2023):** I've found the issue appears to be specific to PySide. With the latest releases, `PySide6` has the issue whereas `PyQt6` does not. I've reported the bug and it's now been fixed in `PySide6 6.6.0`

Comment: I'd start by saying that starting a new QRunnable everytime `data()` is called is not a very good idea. You should at least keep track of indexes that have already been fetched, otherwise you might end up with dozens (or hundreds) of threads...

Comment: Yeah I do that in the actual script, I just removed the checks for the sake of a minimal example

Comment: How do you do that? Are you sure it works properly? Considering you're also porting from Python 2 to 3, there could be something that behaves in a different way. I suggest you to edit your post and include that part.

Comment: I've added a link to the full script, that part shouldn't be the issue though as the slowness happens when any threads are run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug with `PySide` where `QImage` was missing the `allow-thread` flag. It is now fixed and from what I can see, due to be released in `PySide6 6.5.1`.

Since I'm stuck with older versions for the foreseeable future, I found a workaround. By reading the raw bytes *and* sending the image format, then it's able to display the majority of images just as fast.

Here's the code I used to make it work:

```
class ImageLoader(QtCore.QRunnable):
    ...
    def run(self):
        ...
        supportedImageFormats = [f.data().decode() for f in QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()]

        imagePath = self.item.path()
        imageExt = os.path.splitext(imagePath)[1][1:].lower()
      
        # Original way
        if PySide2.__version__ > '6.5.0':
            img = QtGui.QImage(imagePath)
            self.loadedImage.emit(img)

        # Workaround
        elif imageExt in supportedImageFormats:
            reader = QtGui.QImageReader(imagePath)
            with open(self.item.path(), 'rb') as f:
                self.loadedBytes.emit(f.read(), reader.format())
    
        else:
            self.loadedImage.emit(None)

class GridModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    ...
    def setItemPixmapFromBytes(self, item, imgBytes, format):
        """Load an image from bytes."""
        image = QtGui.QImage()
        image.loadFromData(imgBytes, aformat=format)
        self.setItemPixmap(item, image)
   
    def setItemPixmap(self, item, pixmap):
        if isinstance(pixmap, QtGui.QImage):
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(pixmap)
        ...
```

The drawback is certain image formats may not work - in my case I found a bunch of TGA files were not loading. I found a [post from 2017](https://forum.qt.io/topic/74712/qimage-from-tga-with-alpha/11) showing an alternative way to load them, then converted to Python with the help of AI. To implement this, under the `ImageLoader.run` method, you would check the extension, and use `self.loadedImage.emit(loadTga(imagePath))` if a TGA, otherwise proceed with sending the `self.loadedBytes` signal.

```
def loadTga(filePath):
    img = QtGui.QImage()
    if not img.load(filePath):

        # open the file
        fsPicture = open(filePath, 'rb')

        if not fsPicture.is_open():
            img = QtGui.QImage(1, 1, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
            img.fill(QtCore.Qt.red)
            return img

        # some variables
        vui8Pixels = []
        ui32BpP = 0
        ui32Width = 0
        ui32Height = 0

        # read in the header
        ui8x18Header = [0]*19
        fsPicture.readinto(ui8x18Header)

        #get variables
        ui32IDLength = ui8x18Header[0]
        ui32PicType = ui8x18Header[2]
        ui32PaletteLength = ui8x18Header[6] * 0x100 + ui8x18Header[5]
        ui32Width = ui8x18Header[13] * 0x100 + ui8x18Header[12]
        ui32Height = ui8x18Header[15] * 0x100 + ui8x18Header[14]
        ui32BpP = ui8x18Header[16]

        # calculate some more information
        ui32Size = ui32Width * ui32Height * ui32BpP // 8
        bCompressed = ui32PicType == 9 or ui32PicType == 10
        vui8Pixels.resize(ui32Size)

        # jump to the data block
        fsPicture.seek(ui32IDLength + ui32PaletteLength, 1)

        if ui32PicType == 2 and (ui32BpP == 24 or ui32BpP == 32):
            fsPicture.readinto(vui8Pixels)

        # else if compressed 24 or 32 bit
        elif ui32PicType == 10 and (ui32BpP == 24 or ui32BpP == 32): # compressed
            tempChunkHeader = 0
            tempData = [0]*5
            tempByteIndex = 0

            while True:
                fsPicture.readinto(tempChunkHeader)

                if tempChunkHeader >> 7: # repeat count
                    # just use the first 7 bits
                    tempChunkHeader = (tempChunkHeader << 1) >> 1

                    fsPicture.readinto(tempData)

                    for i in range(0, tempChunkHeader+1):
                        vui8Pixels[tempByteIndex] = tempData[0]
                        vui8Pixels[tempByteIndex+1] = tempData[1]
                        vui8Pixels[tempByteIndex+2] = tempData[2]
                        if ui32BpP == 32:
                            vui8Pixels[tempByteIndex+3] = tempData[3]
                        tempByteIndex += 4
                else: # data count
                    # just use the first 7 bits
                    tempChunkHeader = (tempChunkHeader << 1) >> 1

                    for i in range(0, tempChunkHeader+1):
                        fsPicture.readinto(tempData)

                        vui8Pixels[tempByteIndex] = tempData[0]
                        vui8Pixels[tempByteIndex+1] = tempData[1]
                        vui8Pixels[tempByteIndex+2] = tempData[2]
                        if ui32BpP == 32:
                            vui8Pixels[tempByteIndex+3] = tempData[3]
                        tempByteIndex += 4

                if tempByteIndex >= ui32Size:
                    break

        # not useable format
        else:
            fsPicture.close()
            img = QtGui.QImage(1, 1, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
            img.fill(QtCore.Qt.red)
            return img

        fsPicture.close()

        img = QtGui.QImage(ui32Width, ui32Height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        pixelSize = 4 if ui32BpP == 32 else 3

        for x in range(ui32Width):
            for y in range(ui32Height):
                valr = vui8Pixels[y * ui32Width * pixelSize + x * pixelSize + 2]
                valg = vui8Pixels[y * ui32Width * pixelSize + x * pixelSize + 1]
                valb = vui8Pixels[y * ui32Width * pixelSize + x * pixelSize]

                value = QtGui.QColor(valr, valg, valb)
                img.setPixelColor(x, y, value)

        img = img.mirrored()
    return img
```

With all of this implemented, on the test texture library I'm using it on, both Python 2 and my workaround load in 17 seconds. The bugged way in Python 3 takes 34 seconds.